# codeigniter query db using select statement

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I am new to CodeIgniter, please help me to write a select statement in CodeIgniter equivalent of

```
$username='JOHN';
$query=SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE username=$username
```

Just the format, the rest I'll figure out. Thanks.

Comment: Hard to believe that this information can't be found in any tutorial.

Comment: The question explains how much new you are ;). Welcome to Codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

```
$this-db->select('id');
$this->db->where('username', $username);
return $this->db->get('table1');
```

But, as fancyPants said, this is easily findable in all kinds of tutorials around the web. Not a good question.

Comment: Please note he needs to select the **`id`**.

Comment: Edited the post, tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

That would translate to `Active Record`:

```
$username='JOHN';

/* allows you to specify selecting a column */
$this->db->select('id');

/* does the FROM, and WHERE */
$query = $this->db->get_where('table1', array('username' => $username));
```

And to start off, please read the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data).

Answer (score 0):

refer this  codeigniter link

visit: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 0):

One liner to get the **`id`**..

```
return $this->db->select("id")->where("username", $username)->get("table1")->row();
```

OR

Since **`id`** is unique and you're retrieving only one row, add a **`limit 1`** like,

```
return $this->db->select("id")->where("username", $username)->get("table1", 1)->row();
```

Hope this helps :)